# Auth::attempt allways returns false even if informations passed are true

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

i'm on laravel and try to make a user verfication system but i have a probleme with the function Auth::attempt, it returns allways false even if i fix data.

this is my login function code in my controller

```
 $request->validate([
            'username' => 'string',
            'password' => 'required|string',
        ]);
        $credentials = ['username' =>$request->get('username'), 'password' =>$request->get('password')];

        try {

            if(!Auth::attempt($credentials))
                return response()->json([
                    'message' => 'Unauthorized'
                ], 401);

            $user = $request->user();
            $tokenResult = $user->createToken('Personal Access Token');
            $token = $tokenResult->token;
            if ($request->remember_me)
                $token->expires_at = Carbon::now()->addWeeks(1);
            $token->save();
            return response()->json([
                'access_token' => $tokenResult->accessToken,
                'token_type' => 'Bearer',
                'expires_at' => Carbon::parse(
                    $tokenResult->token->expires_at
                )->toDateTimeString()
            ]);

        } catch(Exception $e){
            echo $e;
        }
```

this is my customerProvider for checking because i have in my database MD5 password

```
    public function validateCredentials(UserContract $user, array $credentials)
    {
        $plain = $credentials['password'];

         if(md5($plain) == $user->getAuthPassword()){
            return true;
        } else if($this->hasher->check($plain, $user->getAuthPassword())){
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

my user model

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable, HasApiTokens;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'username', 'password'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];


}
```

this is my auth.php

```
<?php

use App\User;

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Defaults
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option controls the default authentication "guard" and password
    | reset options for your application. You may change these defaults
    | as required, but they're a perfect start for most applications.
    |
    */

    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],

    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'passport',
            'provider' => 'users',
            'hash' => false,
        ],
    ],
    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'customuserprovider',
            'model' => App\User::class,
        ],

        // 'users' => [
        //     'driver' => 'database',
        //     'table' => 'users',
        // ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Resetting Passwords
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | You may specify multiple password reset configurations if you have more
    | than one user table or model in the application and you want to have
    | separate password reset settings based on the specific user types.
    |
    | The expire time is the number of minutes that the reset token should be
    | considered valid. This security feature keeps tokens short-lived so
    | they have less time to be guessed. You may change this as needed.
    |
    */

    'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
        ],
    ],

];
```

Help me please to found a solution..

Comment: Are you using the default authentication or are you trying to use passport to let users login? Can you post your auth drivers configuration?

Comment: I'm using passport

Comment: 'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'passport',
            'provider' => 'users',
            'hash' => false,
        ],
    ],

Comment: What happens if change your if condition to: `if (! Auth::guard('api')->attempt($credentials))` in your controller? Does it still return false?

Comment: I have this error "message": "Auth driver [jwt] for guard [api] is not defined.",
    "exception": "InvalidArgumentException",

Comment: Seems like the config/auth.php has the api driver set to `jwt` and not `passport` as you posted for somewhat reason . Did you cache the configuration with `php artisan optimize` or `php artisan config:cache`? If so, try with `php artisan optimize:clear` and double check the edit on the config/auth.php file

Comment: thank you, it works now. you save my day

Comment: I posted that as an answer, so you can mark your question as solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the config/auth.php has the api driver set to `jwt` and not `passport` as you posted for somewhat reason.

If you cache the configuration with `php artisan optimize` or `php artisan config:cache` you have to run `php artisan optimize:clear` to let your updated configuration has effect